# Amazon EC2: How to bind to eth0 and not localhost?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a service running on an EC2 instance that needs to bind to the private IP associated with eth0 and not 127.0.0.1. So I can't just specify 0.0.0.0 as the bind address. The address needs to go in a static config file. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to avoid 0.0.0.0?

Comment: I am setting up stunnels for Redis and its nice for the encrypted tunnel to be on the usual Redis port but binding on the external IP with Redis on 127.0.0.1. It seems I will have to use a different port and 0.0.0.0.

Comment: +1 that makes perfect sense.  I don't know if your "static" config file can use environment variables, or perhaps you can use this in the startup script as an option, but if so, what about putting it into a variable `MY_BIND_ADDRESS=$(ec2metadata --local-ipv4)`, (where MY_BIND_ADDRESS is a variable name I just made up).  This is how I integrate machine-specific info into HAProxy configurations, for example. The `ec2metadata` utility should be installed by default.

Comment: I did think of putting a line in /etc/hosts on startup which is a similar idea. However I have changed the ports in our chef stuff for now.